# export custom element in html from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I'm trying to figure out the simplest possible way to export an html document from org-mode and have it include a working custom-element.

I've tried the following, but it gives me an error message in the console

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<script type="module" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/master/paper-button.js"></script>
<paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
#+END_EXPORT
```

browser error message:

```
Loading module from “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/master/paper-button.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).
```

I took the component from:

https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction

Comment: I presume your browser is Firefox? This does not happen in Chrome (yet?) and in any case has nothing to do with emacs or Org mode. The [Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) link in the console supposedly explains more, but not to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `CORS` issue, not a problem related to `Emacs`, `org-mode` or anything in the editing side.

Modules should be of MIME-type `text/javascript`  or they won't load in *any* browser implementing the specification.In this case this translates to the fact that you're including a file from `raw.githubusercontent.com` which will serve `text/plain` MIME, thus it won't be accepted by browsers.

One possible workaround for this is using an alternative url which will honor the MIME-type as could be [jsdelivr.net](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net) - There may be others, but I just know this one.

So, using this url as `src`:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button.js

will deliver the file without CORS errors.

This will fix your current issue, but probably there it will be more to do to make the thing work as you pretend.